# Downloaded .APK showing activity names at the top of the app?

Tags: android, mobile

I am having an android app developed and the developer sent me the .APK file so I can test the first version.  I have successfully installed the .APK file on my Android device.  However, when I run it, the app shows the name of each activity (with the app's logo) at the top, as shown in the following link http://www.quickid.net/activity.JPG (StackOverflow won't let me post images without a level 10 reputation).  The left picture shows the MainActivity, and the right picture shows the startTrail activity.  So, what's up with that?  Is it some kind of test mode?  How can I run the app as it would normally be run as if it were downloaded from the Play store, without it showing the activity names at the top?  Also, when the app puts text in the notification bar, it says "Rolling text on statusbar" before showing the text.

Answer (score 0):

That is the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), if the developer does not want to use it, he must change the default theme to Theme.Holo.NoActionBar or another that hides the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of most activities is the activity's label. This is set in the App Manifest (AndroidManifest.xml). In `<activity>` you can add the attribute `android:label`.
By default it looks so:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you want to change the label, add a String value, and put this to android:label. If you want no label, add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`. So it looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I will get my developer to try this.  Will this take care of the "rolling text on statusbar" issue in the notification bar as well?